# Creating a new variable by combining multiple rows from 1 column

Tags: r

I have a data frame with many columns.

This is what it currently looks like:

```
ID     Type
1       A
1       B
2       B
2       C
3       A
3       C
```

And this is what I want it to look like:

```
ID     Type
1      A&B
2      B&C
3      A&C
```

I would like to do this without disrupting the rest of the columns. So it's basically going from long to wide form, but just for that one column. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), type = c('A','B','B','C','A','C'))

library(dplyr)
x %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(y = paste(type,collapse="&"))
```

This is just one way, but it is certainly possible.